# Uncertainty whether $\{a^i b^j c^k \mid i+j \le k\}$ is context-free or not

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I'm having trouble with this particular language: $$\{a^i b^j c^k \mid i+j \le k\}$$

If it's not context-free, I don't know how to correctly apply the Pumping Lemma for CFLs; if it is context-free, I don't know how to create a context-free grammar that generates this language.

Which one applies? Can you help me out?

Comment: Keep trying. Try both possibilities until one of them works.

Comment: Suppose you had to generate such a string from the outside in (the first and last characters first, then the second and second-last, etc.) How might you do it?

Comment: Awesome hint, Niel. It's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. $k = i + j + ?$, so the language is $a^ib^jc^?c^jc^i$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a context-free grammar:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
S & → & AC \\
AC & → & a \; AC \; c & \mid & BC \\
BC & → & b \; BC \; c & \mid & EC \\
EC & → & \varepsilon \; EC \; c & \mid & \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray}$$

The $\varepsilon$ in the first RHS of $EC$ is of course not necessary, but it highlights a certain symmetry.

Comment: Bit confusing that AC is supposed to be a single non-terminal symbol.

Comment: I've added the adjective "context-free", from which one can infer that all the left-hand sides consist of a single non-terminals. One can then infer that some non-terminals' names consist of multiple letters. I tried renaming $S$ to $START$ to hit people on the nose with that fact, but it looks ugly (at least in the preview).